# determining a linux filesystem drive types in powershell for automounting

Tags: windows, powershell, filesystems, mount, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I have the windows 10 Dev channel insiders preview (technically it's windows 11), I usually mount my ssd ext4 drives manually for wsl2

**The goal**: sometimes when you have something that won’t work on windows and you want it always to work on wsl2 it becomes tedious to redo the same thing over and over, that is why I would like to automate mounting ext4 fs devices to wsl2 with no interaction from me in the powershell, is that possible?

**Background**: I'm totally new to powershell, and still in the very basics, I'm not planning to waste lot of time on it, because I do have work to do and I have a goal to achieve, forgive my lack of knowledge in windows, I'm a mac and linux guy, but curiosity is a key for learning.

**The problem**: I wonder if there is any command that is similar to the command `df -Th` in linux, that shows all filesystem types either supported by windows like "NTFS/FAT32/FAT16/EXFAT/etc..." or unsupported as "EXT4/EXT3/EXT2/Any other linux based fs type".

`df -Th` sample result:

img: https://linuxhandbook.com/content/images/2020/06/screenshot_7-1.png

> I don't have enough reputation to post it...
> [**Image Source**](https://linuxhandbook.com/df-command/)

**Least Expected behaviour**: I want the result to show ext*, basically I wonder if there is a way to distinguish a linux drive in powershell.

Result structure doesn't matter of how it's displayed, either json or table or list or plain text, no problem as long as I get any valuable result regarding filesystem type.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Listing Disks

The closest command Windows has to `df -Th` is:

```sh
$ wmic logicaldisk get caption, description, providername, volumename, filesystem, size, deviceid
```

which yields, for example<sup>[1](https://danielstrom.org/2019/12/wmic-retrieving-drive-information/)</sup>:

```
$ wmic logicaldisk get caption, description, providername, volumename, filesystem, size, deviceid

Caption Description FileSystem ProviderName Size VolumeName DeviceID
C: Local Fixed Disk NTFS 499099860992 OS \\.\PHYSICALDRIVE0
Q: Network Connection NTFS \\dc1\c$ 42580570112 \\.\PHYSICALDRIVE1
X: Network Connection NTFS \\kfb\HomeFolders\home\stromd 1000202039296 Venus Drive \\.\PHYSICALDRIVE0
```

For more information on wmic's `logicaldisk` operation, see [here](http://support.moonpoint.com/os/windows/commands/wmic/logicaldisk.php).

### Mounting Disks

Once you find a disk, you can mount it via<sup>[2](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/wsl2-mount-disk#mount-the-disk)</sup>:

```sh
wsl --mount <DiskPath>
```

Use the DeviceID you found using `wmic logicaldisk` as the `DiskPath`.

For example, `wsl --mount \\.\PHYSICALDRIVE3`. By default, the filesystem is `ext4`, but if you wish to specify a filesystem, use the `--type` flag.<sup>[3](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/wsl2-mount-disk#mount-the-selected-partitions)</sup>

### Unmounting Disks

You may unmount a mounted disk via the

```sh
wsl --unmount <DiskPath>
```

command.<sup>[4](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/wsl2-mount-disk#unmount-the-disk)</sup> If you omit `DiskPath`, all attached disks are unmounted and detached.<sup>[5](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/wsl2-mount-disk#detaching-a-disk)</sup>

Comment: But will `wmic logicaldisk get filesystem` work for ext4 disks, like the OP is asking?  I see in your example that they are all NTFS, and I'm kind of doubting that Windows can identify a filesystem it doesn't know about.  But can it?

Comment: I wish the answer would give me any result over ext4 specifically, but this only lists the mounted drives in windows such as “C/D/X”, if an unmounted drive was connected I wouldn’t be able to see it, nor knowing  it’s fs data type for the purpose of my automation, btw I’ve gone through  the docs about mounting and therefore I’m asking a better way to auto mount each to it’s specific correct place, windows fs to windows and Linux fs to Linux, I do appreciate your time for answering my question by the way 

Comment: @NotTheDr01ds yes, wmic logicaldisk will list ext4 filesystems (multiple filesystems may exist in separate partitions of the same disk), so this answer fulfills the main question that the OP is asking, "determining a linux filesystem drive types in powershell for automounting"

Comment: @Meno-101 regardless of whether a drive is mounted or not, `wmic logicaldisk` will list it and its filesystem type, whether it is NTFS, EXT4 or otherwise. How you implement auto-mounting the drive is up to you, and is not in the scope of this question.

Comment: Strange! I have these results:
```
> wmic diskdrive get caption,deviceid
Caption                    DeviceID            
Samsung SSD 970 EVO 1TB    \\.\PHYSICALDRIVE0  
SABRENT  SCSI Disk Device  \\.\PHYSICALDRIVE2  
SABRENT  SCSI Disk Device  \\.\PHYSICALDRIVE1 

> wmic logicaldisk get caption,description,providername,volumename,filesystem,deviceid
Caption  Description       DeviceID  FileSystem  ProviderName  VolumeName  
C:       Local Fixed Disk  C:        NTFS                                  
D:       Local Fixed Disk  D:        NTFS                                  
```

Comment: please forgive me for the line breaks, it's not a feature in the comments here 

Comment: Hmm, in that case I'm not sure why it isn't listing one of those devices as a filesystem. I guess an alternative you could try is doing `wsl --mount <DiskPath> --bare` thus allowing you to access it in WSL, and then you can mount it in WSL itself being able to utilize `df -Th` etc. You may have success integrating `df` into Windows and being able to call it through Powershell like so: https://devblogs.microsoft.com/commandline/integrate-linux-commands-into-windows-with-powershell-and-the-windows-subsystem-for-linux/

Comment: @Ntechhh well that has been the manual way that I want to get rid of it, and it's why I'm asking this question.

Comment: Just because you have to run a command under wsl doesn't mean you have to manually run it, you can set up a powershell script that runs on windows and invokes the appropriate commands as necessary.

Comment: It's the part when I insert a drive either usb or sata each time I need to rerun the command to look up each drive then mount each in linux and then I can mount them in as a directory in wsl, that's the part it bothers me.

Comment: In that case, wsl's `wslact` may be of use to you instead of trying to reinvent the wheel: https://github.com/wslutilities/wslu

Comment: Very interesting, they are running powershell into wsl, which I didn't think of, how ever as you said, I don't have to reinvent the wheel if it does exist, I didn't know about it until you told me, thanks for your help. 

Comment: I would like to ask you, if you would kindly update the answer so others might benefit from that as well. :)